# handling multiple graphs in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

two questions:

What is the difference between having multiple `Graph`s in TensorFlow compared to having a single graph and using different `name_scope` for different components?

What is the proper way of handling multiple `Graph`s in TensorFlow? 
Since `Session` only support a single `Graph`, it seems the only way of doing it is to create multiple `Session` instances.